# Fallos de PreviewKeyDown y scroll de ChromiumWebBrowser ocupando una 1/4ª parte del tamaño del control

Tags: c#, windows-forms, scroll

Estoy programando una app navegador web usando el nuGet CefSharp.WinForms.

Y cuando se hace scroll o cambia el contenido del scroll, el control ocupa solo una cuarta parte de su tamaño, en el cuadrante izquierdo superior del Form.

Recuperando su tamaño normal al dejar de hacerse el scroll o el cambio de su contenido (del scroll). He probado a usar la version previa a la actual del nuGet, pero ocurre lo mismo.

En cuanto al uso de teclas, habiendo usado el control WebBrowser del VS, controlaba el evento PreviewKeyDown y podía retroceder o avanzar en la navegación usando las teclas;

Pero estoy viendo que, parece que el control ChromiumWebBrowser, no capta el agregado del evento PreviewKeyDown, por lo que no avanza ni retrocede.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace WebSessionFree
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    {
        public Form1() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();       
        }

        private ChromiumWebBrowser na1;

        public void InitializeChromium()        
        {           
          CefSettings settings = new
          CefSettings();
          Cef.Initialize(settings);             
          na1 = new ChromiumWebBrowser("youtube.com");
          this.Controls.Add(na1);
          na1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;        
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            na1.PreviewKeyDown += new
          PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(na1_PreviewKeyDown);
        }

        private void na1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.F4)            
              {
                Cef.Shutdown();
                Application.Exit();
                return;             
              }

                if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && na1.CanGoBack)
                    na1.Back();
                else if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && na1.CanGoForWard)
                    na1.Forward();
        return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Todos los problemas que detallas, parecen tener que ver con el control. Te contactaste con los autores del mismo?